# Service running on macOS cannot access files on attached volumes

Tags: macos, service, permissions, macos-catalina, volumes

I am running the Logitech Media Server (LMS) on my iMac. The media is on a separate network drive. After a recent macOS upgrade, LMS is no longer able to access the files on the network drive.

I'm currently running macOS Catalina, version 10.15.7.

I can view the files in the Finder:
[image: Finder]

However when I access the services settings, I cannot select the "Shared Music" folder:
[image]

What do I need to do so that the LMS can access the "Shared Music" folder in the Public volume?

Comment: I also posted this issue to the LMS developers: https://github.com/Logitech/slimserver/issues/428

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `ps` command to see how LMS is run, and I found the following:

```
$ ps | grep slim
92012 ttys000    0:00.00 grep slim
90577 ttys004    0:11.23 /usr/bin/perl5.18 ./slimserver.pl -psn_0_44415577
```

The LMS developers told me to grant `perl5.18` full disk access since that is the command that is used to run the service. I tried that, but it didn't work.

I had already given the `perl` command full disk access.
(System Preferenes -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy tab -> select Full Disk Access and add `perl` to the app list.)
[image: Full Disk Access]

So I stopped the LMS service and started it from the command line using the `perl` command instead of the `perl5.18` command:

```
$ /usr/bin/perl ./slimserver.pl -psn_0_44415577
```